# Do compact Lie Groups have discrete U(1) representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Is the following lemma true or false:

**lemma:** Take $G$ a compact Lie group such that
$$\textrm{hom}(G,U(1))\neq\{1\}$$
then
$$\textrm{min}_{h\in\left(\textrm{hom}(G,U(1))/\{1\}\right)^C}\textrm{max}_{g\in G}\left|h(g)-1\right|>0.$$

I think that because of the compactness I can remove the closure and that then the lemma becomes trivial but I'm not sure.

Comment: Compactness of which space? The inf is not over $G$ here.

Comment: I think (but this is just from constructing some examples) that when G is compact that then hom(G,U(1)) is discrete in some sense I can't make precise. For instance when G=U(1) I get hom(G,U(1)) is isomorphic to Z while when G=Z I get that it is isomorphic to U(1). The replacing inf by minimum comes from the fact that when hom(...) is discrete that then hom(...)/{1} is closed...

Comment: Are you taking about continuous group homomorphisms?  Because the image of G has to be compact subgroup of $S^1$, they're all finite - the group of nth roots of 1 for some n. - Sorry, unless it's all $S^1$.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the continuous group Homomorphisms.

Comment: I think that hom(U(1)xU(1),U(1)) is isomorphic to ZxZ. These homomorphisms are just $(u,v)\mapsto u^n v^m$.

Comment: For abelian $G$ you have the Pontryagin dual which is given a topology in which it is discrere when $G$ is compact.  For the non-abelian case I don't know.

Comment: Thank you that already helped a lot.

Comment: I'm looking at your definition again and it makes no sense.  if the image of $h$ is all $S^1$ then that maximum distance is 2.  Otherwise the image is a group of nth roots of unity for some n.  For n even you again always get a maximum of 2.  And for n odd the lowest you get is when n=3, so how do you expect to get close to zero?

Comment: In fact the hom set you need can be described in detail because $G$ can be written as the quotient of $G_1 \times G_2$ by a finite central subgroup $K$, where $G_1$ is a simply connected compact Lie group and $G_2$ is a torus. The question is whether you are willing to use this powerful result here. Edit: strictly speaking what I wrote is true for the connected component of identity; it may also help that for a compact group there are only finitely many components.

Comment: @peters There is no reason that it has to be small just positive. But you might be right that what I wrote is probably not what I meant. Maybe what I mean is more the minimum of the closure. The idea is to take for instance G=Z then the hom(G,U(1)) is probably isomorphic to U(1). Its elements are something like $m\mapsto u^m$ where $u\in U(1)$ and taking the closure of U(1)/{1} gives me U(1) again so the thing will be zero...

Comment: @Blazey Why does simply connectedness help me here?

Comment: In fact, much more is true: If $H$ is a Lie group equipped with a left-invariant metric $d$, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for each nontrivial subgroup $S< H$, the diameter of $S$ is $\ge \epsilon$. In other words, $\sup_{s\in S} d(s,1)\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: @Moishe Are you arguing that if $\left(hom(G,U(1))/\{1\}\right)^C$ does not contain 1 then the result is trivial because the $g\mapsto h(g)$ can be identified with a nontrivial subgroup of $U(1)$?

Comment: @TijlJappens: exactly.